# Holographic remoting remote app using OpenXR on Linux

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, hololens

The documentation at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/holographic-remoting-create-remote-openxr) MRTK page implies that an OpenXR remote app is possible. However, the rest of the article only discusses the `Microsoft.Holographic.Remoting.OpenXr` Nuget package and later, in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/develop/platform-capabilities-and-apis/holographic-remoting-create-remote-openxr#preview-streamed-content-locally) section, specifics of a DX11/12 based implementation.

My question is: Is it possible to develop a Holographic remoting remote app on Linux using a different OpenXR runtime or any other means?

**Edit:** Answers that use WSL2 and/or the new [dxgkrnl](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/directx-heart-linux/) to interface to `Microsoft.Holographic.Remoting.OpenXr` are also welcome, although I'd prefer to keep the server purely on Linux.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Microsoft remoting OpenXR runtime only runs on Windows. It uses D3D internally and various other Windows APIs also for cryptography.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - could you help clarify if there's any way to make this work via WSL2 and `libdxcore`? This makes me sad tho :(

Comment: @Ani We do not have anything further to comment at this time for Linux support for Holographic remoting, but you can add request via feedback hub for future consideration. For how to post feedback request, you can follow this doc: [Send feedback to Microsoft with the Feedback Hub app](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/send-feedback-to-microsoft-with-the-feedback-hub-app-f59187f8-8739-22d6-ba93-f66612949332).